# Servlets/JSP - Unable to access database on SOAP webservice

Tags: mysql, web-services, soap

I am trying to create a simple little webservice on a glassfish server backed by a mysql server on my netbeans

Its designed to be a very simple currency conversion service

Here is what its supposed to do

It takes an amount of money (Always in GBp) as an INT and a currency to convert it in as a string.

The service then looks up that currency from my database table to get the conversion rate with a query like

```
select * from exchange.rates where currency = string
```

Then it performs the simple calculation to convert the money into the currency and returns the amount

The problem is that i have no clue how to call that conversion rate from my mysql server, i tried and tried but nothing happens
i just keep getting the same amount i entered in.

I tried entering euro and 10
I set the rate for that in my database but i just got 10 back out when i tested the webservice

```
 /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "convert")
    public int convert(@WebParam(name = "currency") String currency, @WebParam(name = "amount") int amount) {
        int newamount = 0;
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con =
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exhange",
                    "root", "25587");
            PreparedStatement st =
                    con.prepareStatement("select * from rates where currency = '" + currency+"'");

            ResultSet rs = null;
            rs = st.executeQuery();
 rs.first();
            newamount =rs.getInt("conversion") * amount;

 return newamount;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }

        return amount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whe you use prepared statemen you need to pass the parameter explicitly:

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from rates where currency = ?");
st.setString(1,currency) //Check this
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

// If you are sure that is only one row then you nee to do
String columnX = null;
if (rs.next() != null) {
   columnX = rs.getString(1); //Where 1 is the first column
}
```

Comment: thanks man!
actually i found the error,  i didnt type in the database name properly lol